# Gatsby Contentful search

Tags: gatsby, contentful

I have a Gatsby project which uses Contentful. All good - I can retrieve blogs for example and display them.

But if I want to provide a search facility to search through potentially 1000s of posts and display the relevant results - how can I do this?

I'm not even sure how to start this - presumably the "result page" would be a different route as the current route is already resolved as a static file - but I am not sure how I would route this anyway when Gatsby already has routing.

Anyone got a starter-template for this? Would be good to have one!

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There few ways to approach this;

1. Using Libraries like [elesticlunr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticlunr) for offline search, but it will require you to create the index at build time.

Fortunately, it can be achieved using the [gatsby-plugin-elasticlunr-search](https://github.com/andrew-codes/gatsby-plugin-elasticlunr-search) plugin.

In your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
            resolve: `@andrew-codes/gatsby-plugin-elasticlunr-search`,
            options: {
                // Fields to index
                fields: [
                    'title',
                    'description',
                ],
                // How to resolve each field's value for a supported node type
                resolvers: {
                    // For any node of type MarkdownRemark,
                    // list how to resolve the fields' values
                    ContentProduct: {
                        title: node => node.title,
                        description: node => node.description,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    ],
};
```

2. If your website type is an online documentation, you can make use of [Algolia docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/) feature.

Agolia will scrape the DOM and build the search index automatically and all you are left to do is: to build an interface to render [search results](https://www.algolia.com/doc/paths/build-search-ui/).

3. Using Algolia and collect the search index at build time and upload it to Algolia and guess what: there is [plugin](https://github.com/algolia/gatsby-plugin-algolia) for that.

Comment: thanks Khaled. Nt sure I fully get the resolvers yet but I will look into it. But does this basically mean that the entire list of blogs is downloaded to the client? Couldn't this be problematic?
Also, if lets say I wanted most of the site statically generated but also maybe wanted a page which showed results depending on your authorization, how could i mix these 2 types in one project.
ie Products page might be static for example but then My Orders page is dynamic.
How would I mix a standard React Router app with the Gatsby static one?

Comment: You have complete control over what to index and what not in the code.

As for downloading all the website data you are already doing that when you picked a static site generator as a stack :) However if you worry about the index getting super big I would recommend you use the algolia solution.

You can definitely limit the route here's a detailed document about that https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/building-apps-with-gatsby/.

Comment: I think Some of the other questions can be post in a different question since originally the question was how to add search for a Gatsby powred website

Comment: re downloading all the data - that's what I originally assumed. But if I use gatsby serve on my site, it creates multiple js files. One for each blog post. When I then go to the front page, these are not all loaded. Having gone to the entry point, if I for example delete one of those js files and then try to navigate I get an error. Which implies it is lazy loading. Which means that being able to search them dynamically without loading all the data into the browser would indeed be beneficial. Now admittedly I would expect it to not do it this way but it seems to

Comment: Gatsby serve is only for development purposes you shouldn't be having it in you production server you need to build your website and host just the what's inside the public directory, as for the lazy loading let gatsby worry about that it will make sure to load all necessary code for your component.

Comment: i thought gatsby develop was for dev? My public directory contains these multiple js files after using gatsby build - and that's why it looks like it will only load the text for a specific blog when I navigate to that blog. Therefore passing down the entire data for all blogs in the search page is indeed more burdensome than just a standard build which will only load posts when necessary

Comment: You are not passing all the data you will be building a search index which you will use to identify which entry you are interested in and then you redirect the user to that page, a search index is completely different from the data that you have

Comment: @KhaledGarbaya Thanks a lot for your [_Gatsbyjs+Contentful_ YouTube video series](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_XsS8kgD9Y64ZOug4YKhpw). I took away a lot from it and really appreciate your effort. Have you considered putting out a video on how to implement search when using GatsbyJS and Contentful? I would be particularly interested in the third option you mention above. Since there is no documentation yet for the Gatsby Algolia plugin, I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: Hey i will definitely consider adding a video about search in a Contentful + gatsby website but the approach is the same as i mentioned before